# Calculating how many values are in a column per each index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` which follows this structure:

```
                value           value_1

index_1         abc             300
                abc             235
                abc             359
                abc             167
index_2         def             64
                def             641
index_3         ghi             12
index_4         jkl             1
                jkl             10
```

I am trying to add another column `count` which is the count of `value` per each `index` so that the `df` would look like this:

```
                value           value_1         count

index_1         abc             300             4
                abc             235             4
                abc             359             4
                abc             167             4
index_2         def             64              2
                def             641             2
index_3         ghi             12              1
index_4         jkl             1               2
                jkl             10              2
```

I tried:

```
df.groupby(level=0).count()['value']
```

Which returns the series of the counts I, but when I add it to `df` it all `nan`

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(level=0).count()['value']
```

```
                value           value_1         count

index_1         abc             300             nan
                abc             235             nan
                abc             359             nan
                abc             167             nan
index_2         def             64              nan
                def             641             nan
index_3         ghi             12              nan
index_4         jkl             1               nan
                jkl             10              nan
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: `Use df['count'] = df.groupby(level=0)['value'].transform('count')`

Comment: As always, thank you.